# How to understand "We have not been smoking"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, present-perfect

Given a sentence:

> We have not been smoking

What is the exact meaning the speaker wants to express?

One interpretation:

> We smoked an hour ago, but we stopped smoking after ten minutes, then
>   we smoked again.

Another interpretation:

> We smoked an hour ago, but now we didn't smoke.

Which is correct?

Comment: We did not smoke. We haven't smoked at all. No matter what you think, we have not been smoking.

Comment: 3rd interpretation: *It is not the case that we have been smoking.*

Comment: There's also the [ell.se]

Answer (score 3):

The latter. "We have not been smoking" would normally cover from some unspecified past time until the present.

Comment: Should we not let [ell.se] take care of simple questions as this?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to mean 'We have not been smoking [in the last unspecified time frame]'.

The timeframe is derived from context.

For example:

> 'We have not been fighting!'.

From some children who's parents have just got home, probably means 'We have not been fighting this evening'.

> 'We have not been eating dairy'.

Would have a larger time frame, anywhere from a couple of weeks to a few months.

> 'We have not been smoking'.

It really depends on the context. At a cocktail party where the couple hasn't seen another couple for a while, they may mean that they've quit smoking and haven't smoked in a few weeks/months.

Whereas from a suspicious mother, it might mean that they haven't been smoking this evening.

Answer (score 0):

> We have not been smoking

Usually used when the speaker wants to express that they have not smoked for "X" amount of time and they still do.